# Woocommerce comments subscription

Tags: comments, woocommerce-offtopic, subscription

I want to ask you that I translated all my site's texts but I can not translate comments subscription option on product page.

from which php file I can translate texts?

Thank you in advance :)

Here is the picture ;

[image: Notify options]

Comment: This may be a little tricky but it works. Inspect the text marked in yellow using Firebug or Chrome's Dev tools, then search for the element's id or class in the source files. You can also search for the entire text in yellow in your source files for WooCommerce. Now go through the files in which this text appears and read the code. You will find an action or filter hook that will allow you to translate and return the text.

Comment: Thank you for answer, actually you know I already searched for them on source files of WooCommerce but couldn't find it. This is the source code; <label class="subscribe-label" id="subscribe-label" for="subscribe_comments">Notify me of follow-up comments by email.</label>

Comment: I see you found the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Those options do not appear from the core but, they're are part of the `Jetpack` plugin. You should check with Jetpack files.

Off-topic: I personally would prefer to disable these on Woocommerce pages.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you a lot, I found them on Jetpack plug-in as you said and disable them.

Comment: You're most welcome. All the best :)